# Return Type: If conditional call to sys.exit() in function

Tags: python, python-typing

Assuming I have the following function in a console script (1):

```
def example(x: int) -> typing.Union[typing.NoReturn, int]:
    if x > 10: # something is wrong, if this condition is true
        # logging
        # cleanup
       sys.exit()
    return x * 10
```

Is the return type correctly specified? As NoReturn means that the function *never* returns (cf.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), this seems wrong. But mypy doesn't complain about the combination of `Union` and `NoReturn`.

This seems wrong (2), as `SystemExit` isn't returned, but raised by `sys.exit` (and leads to errors with mypy):

```
def example(x: int) -> Union[SystemExit, int]:
    ...
```

What about (3):

```
def example(x: int) -> Union[SystemExit, int]:
    if x > 10: # something is wrong, if this condition is true
        # logging
        # cleanup
       return sys.exit()
    return x * 10
```

This seems plausible, too (4). However, the signature hides the special behaviour then:

```
def example(x: int) -> int:
    if x > 10: # something is wrong, if this condition is true
        # logging
        # cleanup
       sys.exit()
    return x * 10
```

Comment: I believe (4) is the most correct one, since the function `example` always returns when it's called with the proper arguments. If it program exits, nothing was returned.

Comment: I agree with (4) as well. Short of using `try: ... except: pass` to wrap the entire function body, there's no way to write a function that *can't* raise an exception, so it's not really worth reflecting in the type signature that a function *might* not return.

Comment: (3) is definitely out; `return sys.exit()` doesn't say it returns `SystemExit`; it says it returns whatever `sys.exit()` returns (which *also* isn't `SystemExit`).

Comment: Exceptions are simply outside the scope of a *static* typing system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoReturn` is used to state that function **never** returns.

If we annotated as `NoReturn` all functions that may not return control, this would apply to all functions that may throw an exception.

Answer (score -4):

what if instead of calling sys.exit() inside the example function you call it outside

```
def example(x: int) -> int:
    if x > 10: # something is wrong, if this condition is true
        # logging
        # cleanup
        return [] # or x = []
    return x * 10
```

then in your code

```
 if x==[]:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Just raise an exception (other than `SystemExit`) instead of returning a special value; that's what exceptions are *for*.